How can I add a trust policy to a role using boto3?
This question is somewhat connected to the discussion found here:
How can I use the AWS CLI to add a trust policy to a role?
Previously, I encountered a problem adding a policy via the AWS CLI. It was resolved thanks to the solution shared by @john-rotenstein
However, I'm encountering a similar issue when attempting to add the policy using the boto3 library.
Currently, I am already using the full content of the policy.
Code:
trust_policy = {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": f"arn:aws:iam::{account_id}:user/{user_name}"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}

iam.update_assume_role_policy(
    RoleName=role_name,
    PolicyDocument=json.dumps(trust_policy)
)

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\path\to\source\aws.py", line 222, in <module>
    create_user()
  File "\path\to\source\aws.py", line 197, in create_user
    iam.update_assume_role_policy(
  File "\path\to\venev\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 565, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "\path\to\venev\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 1021, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.MalformedPolicyDocumentException: An error occurred (MalformedPolicyDocument) when calling the UpdateAssumeRolePolicy operation: Invalid principal in policy: "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:user/teli_tst_user"


After few trial and error, I was able to solve the issue.
Initially I was trying to create the policy soon after the role is created in the script.
When I added a wait for 60 seconds, the code executed without any error.
Below code returns error:
iam = boto3.client('iam')
iam.create_role(...)
iam.attach_role_policy(...)
iam.update_assume_role_policy(...)

Below code executed without error:
iam = boto3.client('iam')
iam.create_role(...)
iam.attach_role_policy(...)
time.sleep(60)
iam.update_assume_role_policy(...)


To reproduce your situation, I did the following in the IAM management console:

Created a new IAM Role for use with EC2
Edited the Trust Policy:

I used the policy you have shown in your question
I inserted an ARN to one of my own users


It successfully saved without error

I the repeated the process, but edited the Trust Policy using your code. It worked successfully.
As an experiment, I then edited the policy and changed the 12-digit Account number to 111111111111. I then received the same error as you experienced: Invalid principal in policy
Therefore, the problem seems to be that you are using an invalid IAM User ARN in the Principal.

Hi @john
I am pretty sure I am using valid ARN.
I am able to create the policy using AWS CLI, with the same JSON.
